# Let $X$ be the ordinal space $[0,2\Omega)$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the ordinal space $[0,2\Omega)$, with the order topology, where $\Omega$ is the first uncountable ordinal. Can we say that, like $[0,\Omega)$, this space is locally compact?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every ordinal space $[0,\Gamma)$ is locally compact, for the simple reason that all "closed" ordinal spaces $[0,\alpha]$ are compact. (So $[0,\alpha]$ is a compact neighbourhood of $\alpha$ for all $\alpha < \Gamma$.)